# Style sheet issues in Load Balanced SharePoint 2010 Application

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, load-balancing

I have researched quite a bit and found no answer so I decided to make a post on this.

I have a fully working SharePoint 2010 Site Collection with some CSS and JavaScript resources to customize the look and feel of the site.
Everything is checked in and published and **the site was working fine until we load balanced the two Frontend Servers**.*

The problem is that, if - and only if - the site is opened through the load balancer, **everyone gets some disrupted design issues AFTER clicking Internet Explorer (8) refresh button**.
Moreover, **SharePoint Designer does not work** while using the LB as well:

"An error occurred accessing your Microsoft SharePoint Foundation site files. Authors - if you are authoring against a Web server, please contact the Webmaster for this server's Web site. WebMasters - please see the server's application event log for more details."

So this situation is not a problem on the following situations:

- Open the site inside any of the servers or using a direct hosts entry to one of the servers (not using the Load Balancer)
- IE10+ or another browser is used
- Ctrl+F5 on IE8 using the LB

Similar (unanswered questions):
http://www.networksteve.com/enterprise/topic.php/Styles_&_JSs_loading_errors_in_load_balancing_sharepoint_farm_wh/?TopicId=49098&Posts=3

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/279b72ba-ede4-44b1-8429-1f2ff4d80c32/401-unauthorized-error-while-connecting-to-web-service-sharepoint-ipfs?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Note:

- Fiddler does not show any relevant output, apart for some suspicious 401s that also appear when the site works
- ULS Logs do not show any relevant authentication, permissions or other entries when the issue happens
- As any medium/large company with intranet restrictions, we really need to support IE8. Also, SharePoint Designer does not work even if IE10 is installed.

Comment: I think your "suspicious" 401s are the clue. Based on that I am assuming these sites aren't anonymous and use Windows authentication. 401s are part of the normal NTLM challenge response process. Seems like the LB is disrupting that somehow, and that is where I would start looking.

Comment: my guess as well. problem is the guys that take care of the LB don't know what to do either. seems like they are using non-MS software, which is not as straight-forward to set up, and they are saying that everything "should work". maybe there is some specific step I can ask them to double check or something...

Comment: it looks like the problem is that accessing through the LBs the site falls back to IE7 due to compatibility mode.

Comment: What LB are you using? How do the headers of the requests look different between LB traffic and non-LB traffic?

Comment: IE8 always fallsback to compatibility mode if site is in the intranet zone.

Comment: X-UI-Compatible is defined to IE=8.

so what happens is behind the LB, after refreshing the page in IE8 it goes to what it looks to be IE7 rendering.

I guess I can either add IE7 support or try to troubleshoot the LB

Answer (score 1):

the frontend servers were behind an F5 load balancer.

for some reason, sites rendered through the LB were displaying with IE7 rendering.

the solution was to add IE7 support to the branding solution, although it could work with a local browser tweak (unchecking "show intranet sites in compatibility mode").

I now tend to ask that LB caches are cleared whenever I have FE specific design problems